# Java URI Builder build method replacing "?" character in the path

Tags: java, api, uribuilder

I have an API at the following path

```
/v0/segments/ch/abc/view/status/ACTIVE?sc=%s&expiryGteInMs=%d
```

I am building a Client using the URIBuilder in Java.

```
return UriBuilder
      .fromUri(config.getHost())
      .path(String.format(config.getPath(),request.List(), request.getTime()))
      .build();
```

The request contains a list to be substituted in place of %s and the time to be substituted in place of %d. But the request being formed has a path like this

```
/v0/segments/ch/abc/view/status/ACTIVE%3Fsc=FK,GR&expiryGteInMs=1611081000000
```

Basically the "?" character is being replaced by %3F. Can somebody help me with this, please?

P.S: I know that we can use the ".queryParam" option available in URIBuilder. Looking for the actual reason why this is happening?

Comment: Which URIBuilder are you using? Which library/ framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably library that you are using is encoding url, and `?` encodes to `%3F`.
Why this happens(in short): url could contain only specific set of character, and `?` is not one of them, so, in order to transfer this character, we should encode it (so called [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)).

***A bit longer explanation*** (taken from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)):

URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet.

URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.

Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.

URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

Comment: Thanks much for your help! I changed the config to take only the path and used queryParams for adding the parameters.

Comment: Glad to hear that my answer helped you. Please mark it as accepted so other people will see it was solved.